# I need a formula to search a term in a specific row and add up data in column below said row

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a daily sales report for my business. I can download all the data in CSV and copy it into sheets. I wish to search for a term in a particular row e.g "Gloves" and then add the data up in the column below.

Unfortunately the column will move left or right depending on what products we have sold that day.

Here is an example of the sheet in question - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KAxZ9kJqwblxQW2YP-58MUh_zvbmtj91CWuQmlbDI60/edit?usp=sharing
In this example I am trying to add up the column below "Safety Glove (Values)" and put the answer into "H53". The answer is $25, but I just don't know the formula to get there.

Ill highlight the relevant cells in pink.

If I can get this formula right it should be replicable for the rest of the report.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this all day!

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(A:AZ,, MATCH(G53&" (Values)",A$2:AZ$2,0))),0)
```

I observed that Phone Pouch BUY in the table reads BUY Phone Pouch. If you could stablish exactly the same names but without the " (Values)" you can just drag this formula and will find automatically each column and sum it